# Unable to show location details in google map using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot few locations in google map. I have two arrays containing latitudes & longitudes of certain places.
Then, using that array, I have to plot them into google map & have to add markers for the places. I did that.

Now...On clicking a marker, an information window should pop up showing details about that place. I tried doing it. But don't know what, nothing happens.

Also you can find the JavaScript code down below.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code.

```
var map;
var marker1;
var marker2;
var lat_array = [7.170000076293945,
    9.819999694824219, 8.470000267028809];
var lon_array = [79.87000274658203,
    78.06999969482422, 76.94999694824219];
var contentString= new Array();

function initialize() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.170000076293945, 79.87000274658203)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    var count_total = lat_array.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count_total; i++) {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_array[i], lon_array[i]);
        bounds.extend(myLatlng);
        var image = 'mapmarkers/you-are-here-2.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'I am here' /*,
            icon: image */
        });
         contentString[i] = '<div id="content">'+
                            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+lon_array[i]+'</h1>'+
                            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                            '<p><b>ICAO:</b>'+lat_array[i]+'.</p>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>';
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
                         (
                           {
                            content: contentString[i]
                           }
                         );

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
                        {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });

   map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**UPDATE:**

**I forgot to initialize content string array. Now it's done. But info window is not showing correct details. On whichever marker I click, info window is shown only for one location.**

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cs15871p/1/)

Comment: the console speaks to you: `Uncaught ReferenceError: contentString is not defined `

Comment: Mozilla Firefox's console didn't speak anything to me when I run that page locally. @Alex

Comment: Forgot to initialize contentString. Now its done. But error still remains. @Alex

Comment: Someone please tell me how is this question off-topic??? I did provide source code, asked for the bizarre behavior of the code. I provided everything. @T J is pissed off as I didn't accept his answer as final. So he started this wave. I didn't update the question based on the answer. Check the edit status. People like @T J makes it hard for new users to ask something. He downvoted the question. Disgusting.

Comment: It's true I removed the old fiddle & added a new fiddle. Both the fiddles are same. Only change that I made in New Fiddle is initializing an array. Thanks to @Alex who pointed out that.

Comment: i dont understand how this would be offtopic at all, i will try to reopen it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in JavaScript does not create new scopes for `if / for` blocks, each click on each marker will always correspond to the last created one, create a closure/ new scope in your for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < count_total; i++) {
  (function() {})(
    ...
  );
}
```

Working code:

```
var map;
var lat_array = [7.170000076293945,
    9.819999694824219, 8.470000267028809];
var lon_array = [79.87000274658203,
    78.06999969482422, 76.94999694824219];


function initialize() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.170000076293945, 79.87000274658203)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    var count_total = lat_array.length;
    for (i = 0; i < count_total; i++) {
        (function(){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_array[i], lon_array[i]);
        bounds.extend(myLatlng);
        var image = 'mapmarkers/you-are-here-2.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'I am here'
        });
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+lon_array[i]+'</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>ICAO:</b>'+lat_array[i]+'.</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
        (
            {
                content: contentString
            }
        );

                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()
                        {
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        });

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
            })();
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs15871p/2/)

Comment: I think it's a little cleaner if you use a closure just for the creation of the click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/gL8tcdrg/

Comment: Thanks. Point noted. @lost-theory